# DRF send new activation code to registerd user that is not active

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

this is django rest framework project . this time i want to resend account activation code to registered user(that is not active at the moment) i wrote view like this but i get server response that say: user account is disabled ... i know user is disabled right now but i want to send new activation code to him according his/her email and id..

note: im using jwt for authentication in my app

this is my view:

any suggestion for me to solve this issue? 
and about my view is it correct way?

```
class ResendActivationCode(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    activation_code = code_generator()

    def get(self, request):
        print(request.user)
        capname = str('re' + request.user.id)
        iscached = cache.get(capname)
        if not iscached:
            cache.set(capname, 1, 120)
            email = request.user.email
            Profile.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).update(**{'activation_key': self.activation_code})
            subject = "complete you registration"
            message = "Thankyou. please enter this code to done your registration progress {}".format(self.activation_code)
            html_message = "http://localhost:4200/accounts/activation/{}".format(self.activation_code)
            froms = "mail@gmail.com"
            # html_template = render_to_string('mail/reg_mail.html', {})
            send_mail(
                subject,
                message,
                froms,
                [email],
                html_message=html_message,
                # fail_silently=False,
            )
            return Response("ok")
        else:
            return Response("time limit")
```

and this is related model: (this is profile model that have relation to User table and have activation_code field to store code)

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    job = models.CharField(default="",max_length=250, null=True)
```

server response:

```
detail":"User account is disabled."
```

Comment: Where `User account is disabled` message is coming from? Is there some kind of middleware or something?

Comment: when i send request to this view

Comment: i think its default message for django any request will response by 401 response code and that message because user not active

Comment: There is no such message in django or rest-frame-work, do a global search for this string and you will see where it is coming from

Comment: i forgot to say im using jwt i think that error refer to that @Sardorbek Imomaliev

Comment: @finfin please add the whole traceback, will provide more insights to solve your issue.